# How can I ensure the refresh of a sub component's props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I have a problem with RTK queries : I have a first component that encapsulates a table. When a refresh occurs - for example when I delete some data - the parent component receives the data and passes it to the child through props but the Table is never updated. So the deleted results still appear on the table.

What is the proper "react/redux" way to generate a refresh of the table ?

Here's some code :

```
const Results = (props) => {


    const router = useRouter()

    const { data, error, isError, isLoading, isFetching } = useGetItemsQuery();

    if(isLoading) {

        return ( 
            <>
                <Spinner animation="border"  size="sm" role="status" />{' '} Please wait while Loading...
            </>
        )
    }
    if(isError) {
        return (
            <>
                <Alert key="warning" variant="warning" style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>
                        Warning - There was an error with the request :  {error.error}
                </Alert>
            </>
        )
    }


    const sizePerPageList = [
        {
            text: '5',
            value: 5,
        },
    ];

    if (data){

        

        return(
            <>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Body>
                        Traffic results
                        <TableResults data={data} sizePerPageList={sizePerPageList} />
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>                
            </>
        )   
    }
}

export default Results;
```

And for the second component with the table :

```
const TableResults = (props) => {

  
    console.log('props - data ', props.data);

    const data = React.useMemo(
        () => props.data,
        []
      )

    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: 'bla bla',
                accessor: 'blabla', 
            }
           
        ],
        []
    )



    const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
      ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
        const defaultRef = React.useRef()
        const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef

        React.useEffect(() => {
          resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate
        }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate])

        return (
          <>
            <input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
          </>
        )
      }
    )
    

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        page, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
        // which has only the rows for the active page

        // The rest of these things are super handy, too ;)
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        pageOptions,
        pageCount,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        setPageSize,
        prepareRow,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize, selectedRowIds },
        visibleColumns,
        preGlobalFilteredRows,
        setGlobalFilter,
        selectedFlatRows
      } = useTable({ columns, data }, useGlobalFilter, useFilters, useSortBy, usePagination, useRowSelect, 
      hooks => {
        hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
          // Let's make a column for selection
          {
            id: 'selection',
            // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
            // to render a checkbox
            Header: ({ getToggleAllPageRowsSelectedProps }) => (
              <div>
                <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllPageRowsSelectedProps()} />
              </div>
            ),
            // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
            // to the render a checkbox
            Cell: ({ row }) => (
              <div>
                <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
              </div>
            ),
          },
          ...columns,
        ])
      } )





    return (
      <>
        <DeleteItemButton items={selectedFlatRows} />
      
        <BTable {...getTableProps()} striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                  <th
                    {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
                  >
                    {column.render('Header')}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {page.map((row, i) => {
              prepareRow(row)
              return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {row.cells.map(cell => {
                    return (
                      <td
                        {...cell.getCellProps()}
                        style={{
                        //   padding: '10px',
                        //   border: 'solid 1px gray',
                        //   background: 'papayawhip',
                        }}
                      >
                        {cell.render('Cell')}
                      </td>
                    )
                  })}
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </BTable>
        <div className="pagination">
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>>'}
        </button>{' '}
        <span>
          Page{' '}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{' '}
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page:{' '}
          <input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={e => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
              gotoPage(page)
            }}
            style={{ width: '100px' }}
          />
        </span>{' '}
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
        </>
      )
}
export default TableResults;
```

The DeleteItemButton will generate a simple RTK query that is functioning very well, and that triggers a refresh of the data from the main component :

```
 deleteItems: builder.mutation({
        query(data) {

            // send array
            let sanitized;
            sanitized = keywords.filter(item => item);
            
            const data = {
                items: sanitized
            }
            //console.log('data: ', data);
          return {
            url: `items`,
            method: 'DELETE',
            body: data
          }
        },
        invalidatesTags: ['Items']
      }),
```

The app is running under nextJS. Any help appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Is this a minimal example to describe your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper "react/redux" way to generate a refresh of the table?

The correct way to refresh your data is by using the `providesTags` and `invalidatesTags` features of RTK query, which you are already doing.

The reason that your table is not refreshing is because you explicitly told it to ignore all changes to `props.data` and to use the initial value for all subsequent renders.  This is obviously not what you intended, but it's what you're doing here:

```
const data = React.useMemo(
        () => props.data,
        []
      )
```

A `useMemo` with an empty dependency array will only execute once.  Generally speaking, all variables which you use inside the `useMemo` should be included as dependencies.  So the dependencies array should be `[props.data]`.

Of course this particular `useMemo` does not *do anything* and can be safely deleted.  It would make sense to have a `useMemo` if you were doing some reformatting of the `props.data` variable and wanted to only execute the reformatting when the value of `props.data` changes.

```
const data = React.useMemo(
   () => someExpensiveComputation(props.data),
   [props.data]
);
```

Comment: Omg i didnt see this !!! Thanks a lot for finding this bug !

Comment: Just as a side note, React.Memo is needed for react-table